# exclude data.sql from Spring boot jar

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to exclude my data.sql and schema.sql from the Spring boot application jar.

So far I have tried several options but they do not seem to work. This is my POM configuration.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>data.sql</exclude>
                        <exclude>schema.sql</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: try <exclude>**/data.sql</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/schema.sql</exclude>

Comment: it did not work still there

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot enables it by default and loads SQL from the standard locations schema.sql and data.sql.If you want to disable this you can try,

```
spring.datasource.initialize=false
```

in **application.properties** or if you want to change default scheme or data scripts locations you can do it with,

```
spring.datasource.schema=
spring.datasource.data=
```

Comment: Hi @mrt I tried your solution and i get an error [/../../../sql/schema.sql] has been normalized to [null] which is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this annotation on top of your test method

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
```

Your *application-test.properties* should have  something like this

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/database/seed.sql
```